# What is so bad about puns?

Tags: history, humor, puns

Many times I've heard of 'pun intended' or 'pun not intended', which I see as a form of excuse in the English-spoken world. However, I can not wrap my head around why are you constantly excusing/explaning something so innocent(?) as pun.

What I am giving off constantly saying 'pun intended'? What's the purpose of constantly saying 'pun (not) intended'?

We don't excuse puns in my native language, in my country, we just laugh it off.

Comment: Actually, the only good puns are bad puns.

Comment: ["A pun is the lowest form of humor - except on Yahoo answers where it is the highest"](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120708072952AAddEPV)

Comment: ***No pun intended. None taken.**: http://wishydig.blogspot.it/2008/04/no-pun-intended-none-taken.html

Comment: I once told TEN puns in a row, hoping that at least one would get a laugh... but no pun in ten did.

Comment: But seriously folks, this is a question about etiquette rather than English.

Comment: @DigitalChris you are an incorrigible punster. Remind us not to encourage you in the future :) .

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard someone say "pun intended". That would be pretty weird.

Comment: @Kat I've both heard and used it. I've never heard anyone say “pun not intended”, though, as written in the question—it's always “no pun intended”.

Comment: A good pun is its own reword.

Comment: Puns make bad jokes - they're just not punny.

Comment: There may be a cultural difference: in English a really good pun is often acknowledged with an "oooh" groan: the better the pun, the bigger the groan.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I've always heard "no pun intended" rather than "pun not intended" too.

Comment: On an interesting side note, you might like to read [Jokester](http://www.sffaudio.com/podcasts/TheJokesterByIsaacAsimov.pdf) by Isaac Asimov. It proposes a very interesting theory (fictional) about what puns are really for.

Comment: @Mitch   A pun is the lowest form of humor, but poetry is verse.

Comment: Mandatory [xkcd reference.](https://xkcd.com/559/)

Comment: I don't think anyone has answered the question why puns are considered -- or spoken of (even jokingly) as -- "bad" or "low". Why do we groan... especially at the cleverest puns?

Comment: I read a while back that the brain processes puns in a different region of the brain than it does other types of jokes. Idk if this is true but it sure feels like it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use "no pun intended"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111610/how-to-use-no-pun-intended)

Comment: @Adamawesome4 considering the venue, I have to point out that “it’s” means “it is” and you meant to use the pronoun “its”.  And that remark is getting a lot of attention.

Comment: @JDługosz Noticed this morning. Too many upvotes to delete it tho :/

Comment: Bribe a diamond mod to edit it for you.

Comment: I'm only here for the comments.

Comment: Puns are for children, not groan ups.

Comment: If you didn't mean to do it would you say it was punintentional?

Comment: Just like this post has pun intended. It's more punny.

Comment: "The lesser of two weevils"..."he who would pun would pick a pocket" - dialog from Master and Commander (the Russell Crowe movie), suggesting a disdain for puns going back to 1805 or thereabouts.

Comment: I can't tell a good pun, but @PeterBocan.

Comment: What do mods value most on this site to bribe them?

Comment: My problem with this phrase is that, by using it, the pun *had* to be intended. The writer recognized that they made a pun but left it in anyway. So, the pun was intended, and the writer is just saying "look at me" by pointing it out. Avoid at all costs.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It's not generally to excuse a pun, but to draw attention to it.

Sometimes "no pun intended" is an edit, or when the author/speaker realised an accidental pun (and in the case of writing decided to leave it in). In speech sometimes the accidental pun (or indeed any humour) may be inappropriate but it can't be edited out once said. In that case an excuse may be needed.

Sometimes puns are regarded as a low form of humour when planned, so "no pun intended" can mean "that just came out by itself" and may not be true. Other times they can be rather subtle and "(no) pun intended" highlights the wordplay and gives a pause to process it.

There are some cases in which it is used to excuse a pun: In technical writing the choice of terminology can be very restricted — everyday synonyms can mean completely different things.  In this case the best phrasing may well lead to an inadvertent pun that is kept and the reader is asked to ignore it.

Comment: I agree with the 2nd and 3rd paragraphs, but not the first. In textbooks, in particular, potential puns arise because of the terminology being used (and as a math student who prefers the more conversation style of textbook, I see this rather frequently)...and when the author says "no pun intended," I take it to mean "please interpret that literally, because that's how it's meant to be read." I wouldn't calling that "drawing attention to a pun," unless it's to point it out before you say "...and now that you know it's there, please ignore it." (Like a tempting self-destruct button, perhaps.)

Comment: @ghorahn that's a good point.  I hadn't considered technical writing where a pun was a direct result of using the most appropriate language.  Edited.  Do you have an example?

Comment: This derogatory attitude towards puns is strictly part of our culture. In many if not most other cultures what we call puns -- word play, double meanings, joking around, refusing to be pompous -- is highly valued and not derogated at all.

Comment: @JohnLawler it's only in some contexts though. Perhaps formality and pomposity are too closely linked in English culture - otherwise wordplay might be more useful in things like debating.

Comment: Nice answer. It would be fun to see it fleshed out with examples.

Comment: bad kind of puns called groaners. And I think, the main  difference between them how much skill is used and what topic is. Perhaps, accidental puns   often are accepted better, so "no pun intended" can be both psychological and humorous addendum, but with groaner it  makes things only worse. No pun intended often used in computer chat society when person is too lazy or too screw-eyed to spot and fix the wordplay (if it was a naughty\inappropriate one).

Comment: If someone accidentally say a pun and want people to disregard it by saying "no pun intended", you are kind of doing the opposite. At the stage where the pun is "out", some people may have noticed it and ignored it, some may have noticed it and thought a bit on it, and some may not have noticed it at all. By adding "no pun indeed" you make sure that every single one is now focusing on the pun.

Comment: @NoOneSpecial yes. The speaker may think it's more important to downplay the pun for those who have heard it, or may choose to hope that no one has.  Or they may instinctively excuse it before thinking

Answer (score 18):

> However, I can not wrap my head around why are you constantly excusing/explaning something so innocent(?) as pun. [...] We don't excuse puns in my native language, in my country, we just laugh it off.

I think you might be slightly overthinking how much we actually care about puns.

You've probably seen references to puns in internet comments, mostly because that's an informal context and because it's easier to make puns using written language. But in "the real world" you won't hear people referring to puns nearly as often as you do on the internet. This is a non-issue for us, just like it's a non-issue in your native language.

I will say that this depends entirely on context. Obviously you wouldn't include a bunch of puns in a speech you're giving at a funeral or at an important work meeting, but that's probably true in your native language as well.

Comment: I bet there were a few at Terry Pratchett's funeral, among others, but on the whole you're right.

Comment: Yep, I get the feeling OP has been spending too much time on reddit.

Comment: Depends ... the band rehearsals of my band *Arcsign* could probably be filmed and presented as stand up comedy. Everybody is trying to one up the puns and an *Arcsign High Five*, a high five from every other band member, is only given to the best of puns.

Comment: @ChrisH those were punes, or play on words :D

Comment: To be honest, I've never been to anywhere near real English speaking world. (And that sucks...)

Answer (score 14):

## Dispensing with Distraction

Mostly I think it is the speaker saying either *I’m clever, I spotted the accidental pun* or else *I’m funny, I made a pun*, but there is a possible third reason: distraction.

Puns can be distracting, provoking internal questions such as:

- Was it deliberate or not?
- Did they realise?
- Does this guy think he’s funny?

If people start thinking about questions like those about the pun, they may become so distracted by that pun that they may then lose the thread of whatever was being discussed.

By acknowledging the pun, this gives everyone a chance see, appreciate, and instantly forget it so that everyone can concentrate on the actual substance of whatever is being said.

Comment: @T.E.D. You're probably right - it could all be distraction - the speaker is distracted by the pun and fills the gap with the acknowledgement of the pun.

Comment: Note: Since I made my comment, this answer was edited. Not complaining about the edit, but it had the side-effect of making my comment obsolete. I was expressing support for the "third reason" : explaining something that the reader is liable to notice and wonder about (thus distracting from what you are saying).

Comment: There might be fourth reason and fifth (which probably is variant of 3rd).  Fourth might be to tell "I made a joke but I don't believe that it is true", "I'm not being serious". Fifth is also a distraction, but distraction from possible negative effect of the pun itself or current discussion in general, using the pun and addendum to it as a bucket of water on feline "concert".